# 8bit adder not working properly

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm writing a Verilog code to construct an 8 bit adder using 8 full adder. That 8 bit adder should add 2 incoming inputs each of 8 bit bus. Here's the code for the single full adder:

```
module FullAdder(
input a_,
input b_,
input cin_,
output sout_,
output cout_
);
wire temp1, temp2, temp3;

assign sout_ = a_ ^ b_ ^ cin_;
assign cout_ = ((a_ & b_) | (b_ & cin_) | (cin_ & a_));

endmodule
```

And here's the code for the 8 bit adder modue which will call the full adder 8 times.

```
module EightBitAdder(
input [7:0] a,
input [7:0] b,
//input cin,
output cout,  //carry; will be sent as OP, but won't be further used.
output [7:0] sout  //sum, sent as OP
);

wire try;

begin 
FullAdder mg0(.a_(a[0]), .b_(b[0]), .cin_(0), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[0]));
FullAdder mg1(.a_(a[1]), .b_(b[1]), .cin_(try), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[1]));
FullAdder mg2(.a_(a[2]), .b_(b[2]), .cin_(try), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[2]));
FullAdder mg3(.a_(a[3]), .b_(b[3]), .cin_(try), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[3]));
FullAdder mg4(.a_(a[4]), .b_(b[4]), .cin_(try), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[4]));
FullAdder mg5(.a_(a[5]), .b_(b[5]), .cin_(try), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[5]));
FullAdder mg6(.a_(a[6]), .b_(b[6]), .cin_(try), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[6]));
FullAdder mg7(.a_(a[7]), .b_(b[7]), .cin_(try), .cout_(try), .sout_(sout[7]));
end
endmodule
```

The problem is that the output is not showing correctly. It always displays the first bit and then fills up the rest of the bits with don't cares (X). What could be the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `try` wire is driven by all the 8 full adders, so this is very likely to result in an `X` value if both driven with `0` and `1` from the full-adder carry out.

Consider making a carry out wire instead, like:

```
wire [7:0] cout;
```

and use the different bits for the different full adders, like:

```
FullAdder mg0(.a_(a[0]), .b_(b[0]), .cin_(0), .cout_(cout[0]), .sout_(sout[0]));
FullAdder mg1(.a_(a[1]), .b_(b[1]), .cin_(cout[0]), .cout_(cout[1]), .sout_(sout[1]));
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm still not clear why the same wire try was giving a problem. All the adders were being executed sequentially, so using same variable(wire) for the carry shouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense when designing software, but when writing Verilog you are actually designing hardware.  This means that the resources, like a wire, is always dedicated for a single connection between an output and one or more inputs, just like on a PCB, and cant be shared for different purposes like for example a variable in software.  So you have to make a dedicated wire for each dedicated connection, which is done with the `wire [7:0] cout`.